# getDisplayName() and getPhotoUrl() without signing in user to android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am creating a login page in android using Firebase Email Password Authentication and I want when a user enters its Email address and shift to password the system automatically get the PhotoUrl and DisplayName and display on the Login page Before a user enters His Full Password.

Comment: only way that i know is add display name and photo url in firebase database and when switch to password get these values

Comment: can you share how to do that?

Comment: yeas I will make na explanation on how to get?

Answer (score 0):

For do what you want **one way** is doing that:

So you have something like that in **firebase database**:

```
ASDEYRDSDDA
   Email: jonh@doe.com
   Display_name: Jonh
   Photo_URL: your_url
WERSWERSDFR
   Email: maria@doe.com
   Display_name: Maria
   Photo_URL: maria_url
```

to get the **data** from **firebase** you only need to create a reference like that:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
```

and the **listener**:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override

                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                               String email=data.child("Email").getvalue(String.class);
                               if (email.equals("jonh@doe.com")) {
                                     //do ur stuff
                                    String displayname=data.child("Display_name").getvalue(String.class);
                                    String photourl=data.child("Photo_URL").getvalue(String.class);

                               }
                        }


                }



                @Override

                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {



                }

            });
```

So it checks in all **childs** if the data that you want exists and if yeas you do what you whant.